# CSS for the Events Calendar plugin

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I use WordPress with "The Events Calendar" plugin and "The Events Calendar Shortcode" plugin. I need to display the upcoming three events on the "About company" page. The events are displayed, and now I need to add CSS to display these events nicely.
By using Inspect element command I see that in the code there are `<ul>`,  `<li>` and `<span>` elements. Could you please help me on how to modify the appearance of these elements?

The full code in the Browser is the following:

```
<ul class="ecs-event-list">
<li class="ecs-event">
    <h4 class="entry-title summary">
        <a rel="bookmark" href="http://www.green-craft.eu/event/parfumerijos-paslaptys/">
            Parfumerijos paslaptys
        </a>
    </h4>
    <img class="attachment-150x150 wp-post-image" alt="ramute" src="http://i1.wp.com/www.green-craft.eu/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/ramparfuma.jpg?fit=150%2C150"></img>
    <span class="duration time">
        <span class="date-start dtstart">
            spalio 12 @ 11:00 am
            <span class="value-title" title="2015-10-12UTC11:00"></span>
        </span>
         - 
        <span class="end-time dtend">
            6:00 pm
            <span class="value-title" title="2015-10-12UTC06:00"></span>
        </span>
    </span>
</li>
```

Do I need to add html table? (And there can I specify the html table in WordPress?)
Or maybe I need to add CSS for the classes mentioned in ul, li and span elements? But I tried to modify the CSS and could not managed it. Searched through forums and articles already :)
Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Kotryna

Comment: You can use the classes in a custom CSS file which is loaded after all the stylesheets. For eg: if you need to modify the color of 6:00 PM, try `.end-time { color: red; }`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Understood, I will do as you say.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to get hand dirty just use this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/). this plugin add an extra css file to your site that overwrite any existing css so you can modify your elements directly. Be careful to use most specific inheritance to avoid changing something else. ex. start always with class `.ecs-event`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Analyzing this plugin.

Comment: @P.Kotryna I use it some times when i have to do quick changes directly from back-end  without accessing ftp or other complication. Any time i used it I had no problem

Answer (score 0):

```
function custom_query_one_tribe_events_list(){ if(!class_exists('Tribe__Events__Main')){return;}ob_start(); add_filter( 'tribe-events-bar-should-show', '__return_true' );  $output=''; $output .='<div class="post-type-archive-tribe_events tribe-js tribe-filter-live events-list events-archive tribe-events-style-full tribe-events-style-theme elementor-default tribe-theme-parent-moscow tribe-theme-child-moscow-child tribe-is-responsive"><div id="tribe-events"><div id="tribe-events-content-wrapper" class="tribe-clearfix"><div id="tribe-events-content" class="tribe-events-list tribe-events-day">'; $argsdefaults = array('posts_per_page'=>5,'orderby'=>'event_date','order'=>'DESC');  $output .= tribe_include_view_list($argsdefaults); $output .='</div><!-- #tribe-events-content --> </div><!--tribe-events-content-wrapper--></div><!-- #tribe-events --></div>';echo $output;wp_reset_query();  return ob_get_clean();}add_shortcode('actus_custom_events_list','custom_query_one_tribe_events_list');

function tribe_events_embed_custom_scripts(){ if(in_array('the-events-calendar/the-events-calendar.php', apply_filters('active_plugins', get_option('active_plugins')))){ if(is_page(6508)||is_page(6535)){   $css_path=Tribe__Events__Template_Factory::getMinFile(Tribe__Events__Main::instance()->plugin_url.'src/resources/css/tribe-events-full.min.css', true );$css_path_embed=Tribe__Events__Template_Factory::getMinFile(Tribe__Events__Main::instance()->plugin_url.'src/resources/css/tribe-events-embed.min.css', true );$css_path_theme=Tribe__Events__Template_Factory::getMinFile(Tribe__Events__Main::instance()->plugin_url.'src/resources/css/tribe-events-theme.min.css', true );$css_path_admin_menu=Tribe__Events__Template_Factory::getMinFile(Tribe__Events__Main::instance()->plugin_url.'src/resources/css/admin-menu.min.css', true );wp_enqueue_style( 'tribe-events-embed-custom-css', $css_path_embed );wp_enqueue_style( 'tribe-events-full-custom-css', $css_path );wp_enqueue_style( 'tribe-events-theme-custom-css', $css_path_theme );wp_enqueue_style( 'tribe-events-admin-menu-custom-css', $css_path_admin_menu ); }  }}add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','tribe_events_embed_custom_scripts');
```

custom code shortcode The events calendar only list display. Two function used have your theme function.php this ways display [actus_custom_events_list] editor tools  or do_shortcode('[actus_custom_events_list]')